# How to login to the MySQL in Ubuntu from Windows?

Tags: login, auto-login, remote-login

How to access MySQL directly with MySQL ac but skip the Ubuntu login?
As I PuTTY to MySQL server in Ubuntu, the first login is Ubuntu account. I would like to skip this part and login to the MySQL server with MySQL account directly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this syntax in command prompt:

```
mysql -h <mysql_server_url> -P <port_number> -u <username> -p
```

Example:

```
mysql -h xyz.rds.aws.com -P 3306 -u root -p
```

Comment: Thanks okcomputer_kid. However, why i cannot login as root but can login as a normal user? and seems i cannot change password?

Comment: Have you lost your root password? If you have lost your password, you have to ssh connect to your ubuntu server , change root password there.

Comment: `mysqladmin -u root -p password newpass`    Use this command to update your root password. Donot replace password with anything. Only replace newpass with your password

Comment: But I can login as root in ubuntu so the password is correct. Any other suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: Problem fixed after grant the privileges to root, thanks.

Comment: Can you accept the answer if it solved your problem? It will help others alot too.